# BigQueryIO.readTableRows - no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that PCollection<Long> conforms to PBegin

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to read data from BigQuery every hour in Beam and write the following codes refer to [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/),

```
pipeline.apply("Generate Sequence",
            GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardHours(1)))
    .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(1))))
    .apply("Read Row from BQ",                         
             BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
             .fromQuery("select col1, col2, col3 from project.market.table ")
             .usingStandardSql())
    .apply("Convert Row",
            MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(MyData.class)).via(MyData::fromTableRow))
```

But this error `no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that PCollection<Long> conforms to PBegin` comes up. Is there any way to fix it?

I have tried through `DoFn` as below. However, I failed to find one way to convert `TypedRead<TableRow>` to `MyData`.

```
pipeline.apply("Generate Sequence",
            GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardHours(1)))
    .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(1))))
    .apply("Read Row from BQ query", ParDo.of(new ReadBQParDo()))
    .apply("Map TableRow", ParDo.of(new MapTableRow()))

static class ReadBQParDo extends DoFn<Long, BigQueryIO.TypedRead<TableRow>> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext pc) {
        BigQueryIO.TypedRead<TableRow> rows = BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                .fromQuery("select col1, col2, col3 from project.market.table")
                .usingStandardSql();
        pc.output(rows);
    }
}

static class MapTableRow extends DoFn<BigQueryIO.TypedRead<TableRow>, MyData> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext pc) {
        
        // stuck here, how to convert TypedRead<TableRow> to MyData??
    }
}
```

Beam version: 2.23.0

Comment: Is this a streaming pipeline and are you trying to read the BQ rows as side input ?

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman, yes, read the BQ row as side input and read data from gcs as streaming pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

In your first snippet, `BigQueryIO.readTableRows()` must be at the root of Pipeline, i.e. it is a `PTransform<PBegin, ...>`.  You're trying to apply it to the output of `GenerateSequence` which is a `PCollection<Long>`.

In the second, you can't use PTransforms from within a DoFn (unless you're literally trying to launch a new Beam pipeline for each element).

Comment: Out of curiosity, Why `BigQueryIO.readTableRows()` must be at the root of Pipeline?

Comment: That's just how it's written. With https://beam.apache.org/blog/splittable-do-fn/ one can write one that goes anywhere in the pipeline.